# Estimates and C.I. of percentiles for a survival function

Tags: r, confidence-interval, survival

In S-plus estimates of percentiles for a survival function can be obtained using the `qkaplanMeier` function (on the results of a call to kaplanMeier) like that:

```
kfit <-kaplanMeier(censor(TIME,STATUS)~1)
qkaplanMeier(kfit, c(.25, .5, .75))
```

How can I do this in R?. Those functions do not exist anymore. What if I also want the (asymptotic) confidence intervals for the percentiles? How can I get the mean for the survival time?

Answer (score 3):

The [CRAN task view on survival analysis](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Survival.html) says:

**Kaplan-Meier:**
The
`survfit`
function from the
[survival](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/index.html)
package
computes the Kaplan-Meier estimator for truncated and/or censored data.
[rms](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rms/index.html)
(replacement of the
[Design$^\dagger$](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Design/index.html)
package)
proposes a modified version of the
`survfit`
function.
The
[prodlim](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prodlim/index.html)
package implements a fast algorithm and some features
not included in
[survival](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/index.html).
Various confidence intervals and confidence bands for the Kaplan-Meier estimator
are implemented in the
[km.ci](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/km.ci/index.html)
package.
`plot.Surv`          of package
[eha](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eha/index.html)
plots
the Kaplan-Meier estimator.
`svykm`
in
[survey](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/index.html)
provides a weighted Kaplan-Meier
estimator.
`nested.km`
in
[NestedCohort$^\dagger$](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NestedCohort/index.html)
estimates the
survival curve for each level of categorical variables with missing data.
The
`kaplan-meier`
function in
[spatstat](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatstat/index.html)
computes the Kaplan-Meier estimator from histogram data.
The
[MAMSE$^\dagger$](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MAMSE/index.html)
package permits to compute a weighted Kaplan-Meier estimate.
The
`KM`
function in package
[rhosp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rhosp/index.html)
plots the survival
function using a variant of the Kaplan-Meier estimator in a hospitalisation
risk context.
The
[survPresmooth](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survPresmooth/index.html)
package computes presmoothed estimates of the main quantities used
for right-censored data, i.e., survival, hazard and density functions.

---

$^\dagger$ Respective packages have now been removed from CRAN repository.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are *correct*, but needlessly complicated, IMHO. It’s actually very easy to do this in R:

```
# We need the ‘survival’ package
library(survival)

# Estimate some sample data
n = 1000
x = rexp(n)
status = rep(1,n)

# Fit model
kfit = survfit(Surv(x, status) ~ 1)
kfit
```

The output is:

```
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(x, status) ~ 1)

       n   events   median  0.95LCL  0.95UCL 
1000.000 1000.000    0.720    0.670    0.777
```

So the estimate of the median is 0.72, with a 95% confidence interval of 0.67–0.77. (The theoretical value for these data is `qexp(.5)` ≈ 0.69). If you want to extract the numbers for later use, or estimate other percentiles, you can use:

```
# Estimate and CI for the median
quantile(kfit, 0.5)
```

Change the `0.5` to calculate point estimates and CIs for other percentiles (e.g. to `0.75` for the upper quartile).

To estimate the mean, you can use `print(kfit, print.rmean=TRUE)`, but *do* read `?print.survfit` beforehand. What you’re asking for may not make sense if you have censored observation times.

Answer (score 2):

The `bootkm()` function in [Hmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) provides bootstraped estimate of the probability of survival, as well as the estimate of the quantile of the survival distribution (through either `describe` or `quantile` applied onto the result of `bootkm`).